# Объект TeleBot не содержит атрибут message_handler, хотя должен

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
import config
import telebot
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Текст')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Я пытаюсь написать бота, который по команде отображает цену на сайте, но по неведомым причинам в telebot'е нет атрибута *message_handler*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Глеб, смотрите мой ответ

Comment: Вообще самый наверняковский способ это удалить проект в PyСharm и с нуля установить `pytelegrambotapi`

Answer (score 1):

```
1) pip uninstall telebot
2) pip install pytelegrambotapi
```

Вот рабочий код

```
import config
import telebot
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def cmd_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Текст')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Удалите модуль `telebot`:

   ```
   pip uninstall telebot
   ```
2. Установите `pytelegrambotapi`:

   ```
   pip install -U pytelegrambotapi
   ```

Comment: Не сработало. Тоже самое...

Comment: @ГлебМалютин Проверьте, что удалили именно в той версии `Python`, что используете. Если уверены в этом, то в `IDE` перейдите в `File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter` и посмотрите, есть ли в списке `telebot`.